# How do I use an Input Box value in a find and replace macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user input value called NewName.

Once this is defined I need to then use this value to be the replacement value in a find and replace macro.

This is the find and replace code -

' Changes the formulas in Report to reference new sheet

```
Sheets("Report").Select
Cells.Select
ExecuteExcel4Macro _
    "FORMULA.REPLACE(""'New Performance'"",""'Performance'"",2,1,FALSE,FALSE,,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)"
Range("H32").Select
Sheets("Report").Select
```

How do I get the replacement value to be NewName followed by Performance? (i.e. replace the "New" with the value of NewName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get the replacement value to be NewName followed by Performance? (i.e. replace the "New" with the value of NewName?

The line `"FORMULA.REPLACE(""'New Performance'"",""'Performance'"",2,1,FALSE,FALSE,,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)"` can be written as

```
"FORMULA.REPLACE(""'" & "New" & _
" Performance'"",""'Performance'"",2,1,FALSE,FALSE,,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)"
```

So simply replace the word `"New"` with the InputBox value.

```
Dim newVal

newVal = InputBox("Please enter the new string")

If newVal = "" Then Exit Sub

ExecuteExcel4Macro "FORMULA.REPLACE(""'" & newVal & _
" Performance'"",""'Performance'"",2,1,FALSE,FALSE,,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)"
```